# Updating a collect ion of key/values isn't giving the desired performance

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have large set of records stored in Collection Object as a Key Value Pairs. I want make use of threads, and I want to iterate over the collection, make a restfull call, update the values in my collection object.

I see the multiple threads access the same Key value pair and update same records. This is not giving me the desired performance .
Can some body help please

Comment: Please add a code example, and specify whether you are using a `Collection` or a `Map`.

Comment: Are you concerned about the performance or the desired result? Your question sounds like you don't want multiple threads update the same record.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to clarify your question.
It looks like you are trying to update the values on your collection, and you want to make that update process faster by using multiple threads, but you need each thread to pick a different key, and right now different threads are picking the same key, which makes it inefficient.

First, there is a design problem in your API, you should be able to make just one call with multiple keys, to update them all in just one call to the API. making a call to the api for each Key is a performance overhead by itself.

Second, if you want to make sure your threads pick different keys, you need to use a different data structure, like a queue, and then each thread will pop a value from the queue, and update that key

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16265902)

Comment: @Shawn Mehan As someone who's done a fair bit of threaded programming, I believe that if the OP implements the advice in this answer, the problem will go away, and as such, I do believe this is an answer.  It does correctly state that the question could be improved, but it does go on to actually answer the question.

Comment: You are right, on your observation, while I am constrained to make multiple calls to the API , to get the values for the Keys, your suggestion to use Que, for the solution looks right for me. I will try the same and come back to you.. Thanks very much for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

- You should use ConcurrentHashMap when you need very high concurrency in your project.
- It is thread safe without synchronizing the whole map.
- Reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock.
- There is no locking at the object level.
- The locking is at a much finer granularity at a hashmap bucket level.
- ConcurrentHashMap doesn’t throw a ConcurrentModificationException if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it.
- ConcurrentHashMap uses multitude of locks.

**Code Sample:**

```
public class ConcurrentHashMapSample {

    public final static int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 5;
    public static Map<String, Integer> concurrentHashMap;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
        performTest(concurrentHashMap);
    }

    public static void performTest(final Map<String, Integer> concurrentHashMap) throws InterruptedException {
        long averageTime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
            for (int j = 0; j < THREAD_POOL_SIZE; j++) {
                executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
                            Integer randomNumber = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 550000);
                            Integer value = concurrentHashMap.get(String.valueOf(randomNumber));
                            concurrentHashMap.put(String.valueOf(randomNumber), randomNumber);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            // Make sure executor stops
            executorService.shutdown();

            // Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

            long entTime = System.nanoTime();
            long totalTime = (entTime - startTime) / 1000000L;
            averageTime += totalTime;
            System.out.println("2500K entried added/retrieved in " + totalTime + " ms");
        }
        System.out.println("For " + concurrentHashMap.getClass() + " the average time is " + averageTime / 5 + " ms\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I will try out , in the context of the sample you have given me.